# NodeJS and MongoDB Query Slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

so running into an issue where I am using NodeJS with Express for API calls. I am fetching all documents in a collection using

```js
    export async function main(req, res) {
    try {
        const tokens = await tokenModel.find({}).lean();
        res.json(tokens);
    } catch {(err) => {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
        console.log('err', err.message)
        }
    }
  console.log('Get Data')
}
```

Now this request works great and returns me the data I need. The problem is I have over 10K documents, and on a PC takes about 10 seconds to return that data, and on a mobile phone it takes over 45 seconds. I know network on phone matters, but is there any way I can increase this? Nothing I have tried works. I keep finding that lean is the option to use, and I am already using it with no success or improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's slow because you are returning all 10k results.

Do you actually need all 10k results? If not, you should consider filtering only results that you actually need.

If not, I suggest implementing pagination, where you would return results in batches (50 per page for example).

In addition, if you are using only some of the fields from the documents, you should tell MongoDB to return only these fields, and not all of them. That would also increase the performance since less data will be transferred through the network.

Comment: Yeah thats what I figured it was. But was hoping there was a way to get all still. So I don't need all 10k Results. But there are multiple values I'd need to filter on. And I do need all fields as I use all the fields to populate a front end. Sounds like filtering to a smaller amount is going to be the way to go then. Thanks all!

Comment: Well, you can send filters to the endpoint and filter based on it. In addition, you can create index for the fields that you are filtering on, which should increase the performance a lot.

Comment: Well the problem is, for what I am building the index wouldn't work because I am returning all results as I need all the data from that document. So the only filter I could use would be against a ranking system I have, but thats an array with 7 different ranks. But that ranking is also updated every 120 seconds as they can change.

Comment: Did you consider putting all the data in memory. So you would fetch all the data on the server initially, and keep it in one variable. Then, when someone requests the data, you can return it immediately. But of course, whenever a new record is created, or existing is updated, you will need to update the cached array too.

Comment: I was thinking of prefetching the data. Thats maybe the route ill go. Ill determine if I need it all first.